# Automatically clear cache

Tags: 8, caching

Theme: Basic 8.x-1.x-dev

I am trying to clear theme data after any change is done to twig files.  I see that rebuildThemeData is here: https://goo.gl/EA2YL4

Currently have this within my .theme file.

```
\Drupal::service('theme_handler')->rebuildThemeData();

\Drupal::service('theme.registry')->reset();
```

Does anyone have this sort of implementation complete and working for an example?
https://www.drupal.org/node/2608470

Answer (score 4):

There are some defaults that ship with D8 in your `sites/default` configuration files that you can configure during development.

The application portion:

```
Open development.services.yml in the sites folder 
and add the following block (to disable twig cache)
        parameters:
          twig.config:
            debug : true
            auto_reload: true
            cache: false
```

There is more information on this [Drupal.org node](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914).

Comment: Thanks Alex, Im actually attempting to do this within the theme in order to make it simpler for other themers to just check a box in the theme settings.    I will modify my question